# c++ loadlibrary - import dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

could you please tell me what is wrong with this c++ code? it always returns E_INVALIDARG

```
typedef HRESULT STDAPICALLTYPE AcquireDeveloperLicense(
    _In_opt_ HWND     hwndParent,
    _Out_    FILETIME *pExpiration
    );
HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary(TEXT("WSClient.dll"));
AcquireDeveloperLicense *acquire_license = (AcquireDeveloperLicense*)GetProcAddress(hDll, "AcquireDeveloperLicense");
FILETIME *pExpiration = NULL;
HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
HRESULT result = acquire_license(hwnd, pExpiration);
```

Comment: The error message tells you what is wrong. One of the arguments is not valid. Did you look at the error code and think what it could imply?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a NULL pointer in the 2nd parameter of `AcquireDeveloperLicense()`.  It expects you to pass in a pointer to a `FILETIME` struct to receive the license's expiration date.  The `FILETIME` is not optional.

Try this instead:

```
typedef HRESULT (STDAPICALLTYPE *LPFN_AcquireDeveloperLicense)(
    _In_opt_ HWND     hwndParent,
    _Out_    FILETIME *pExpiration
    );

HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary(TEXT("WSClient.dll"));
if (hDll)
{
    LPFN_AcquireDeveloperLicense acquire_license = (LPFN_AcquireDeveloperLicense) GetProcAddress(hDll, "AcquireDeveloperLicense");
    if (acquire_license)
    {
        FILETIME Expiration = {};
        HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
        HRESULT result = acquire_license(hwnd, &Expiration);
        ...
    }
    ...
    FreeLibrary(hDll);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a pointer to a variable in which you want the function to store the result, not pass `NULL`. As the [`AcquireDeveloperLicense`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj572812(v=vs.85).aspx) notes `pExpiration` is an not optional *out* parameter and that meas that `NULL` is not a valid value.

```
FILETIME expiration{};
HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
HRESULT result = acquire_license(hwnd, &expiration);
```